# Highcharts xAxis text matching series name

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm facing an issue with my Highcharts-powered component.

Considering the basic column chart JSFiddle example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

My goal is to get the series name (Tokyo, New York, etc...) instead of Jan, Feb, Mar... on the x Axis.

Of course, I also need the columns to be grouped according to the series name. So, in this case, it would be 4 group of columns.

How can I do this ? Should I modify the `categories` block ?

Thanks a lot

---

**EDIT**

I've found the solution and updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j658R/1/

But now, I need another bahvior. How can I specify more than one value for each serie ? For example, for "s1", how can I put 4 values for this series and so get 4 bars above the "s1" label on the X axis ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried editing the categories? Did it do what you wanted? If not, post a fiddle example and explain what you want it to do that it's not doing.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j658R/ I want the series name on the xAxis under its corresponding value. So, in this case, I would like s1, s2, ... s8 instead of only s1 in the xAxis which has no meaning

Comment: do you want a stacked bar chart ?

Comment: you need to add next serie, do you mean somethign like http://jsfiddle.net/j658R/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/j658R/3/ ?

Comment: Or maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j658R/4/ ;) LinkedSeries to one legend item, just play around with `pointPlacement` to position them within category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By separating each data point into a separate series, Highcharts will automatically group the data.

So the first data point of each series will be set to the first category. The second data point of series to the second category, etc.

All you need to do is set this up as a single `series`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/j658R/6/